# Get uncompiled twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using less php and want to implement an uncompiled version of the twitter bootstrap CSS file. But when I download it, I get the compiled version only.

Where do I get the uncompiled less version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that from github [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any resource I can download them all combined?

Comment: Well the `boostrap.less` file *imports* all main .less files. If you want the responsive files as well, then you might want to include `responsive.less`

Comment: I tested the bootstrap.less but sadly lessphp doesn't handle everything the correct way. Thus I thought I combine them first and hoped it works after that. Unfortunately not. I'll have to see why and what lessphp doesn't understand in the bootstrap files :-)

Comment: Presumably you've looked here? http://leafo.net/lessphp/ was there an error you got?

Comment: There was no error message, at least in my documents. lessphp just didn't compile the less files. As I remember there were some expressions that causes the error. After deleting some lines it works, but there are a whole bunch of lines that didn't work.

Comment: Solved it. There was an issue with bootstrap and lessphp v. 0.2. After updating to current v 0.3.5 it works